# python imaplib mail.search is it possible to have a lot of threads each searching for different email?

Tags: python, multithreading, imaplib

I am wokring on a script that utilizes multiple threads, each searching for a different email. The issue is, that I cant use more then +- 20 threads at the same time. I tried two different approaches.

1. Using global mail variable that is logged in into the email and using it in all threads. The issue here was that the code started breaking and i got multiple different errors, which all had some form of "unexpected response" in them.

```
MAIL = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(gmail_host)
MAIL.login(username, app_password)

def search_email():
    MAIL.select("INBOX")
    #do some stuff

for i in range(100):
    thr = Thread(target=search_email)
    thr.start()
```

2. Using a different variable in every thread (logging and creating the mail variable inside of the function i was running threads with). This resulted into "too many connections" error.

```
def search_email():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(gmail_host)
    mail.login(username, app_password)
    mail.select("INBOX")
    #do some stuff

for i in range(100):
    thr = Thread(target=search_email)
    thr.start()
```

I want to ask if there is a way to make this work. Thank you.

Comment: so don't use more than 20+ threads? what's the issue with using only 20?

Comment: @gold_cy the issue is speed, well its not really an issue but i wanted the script to be faster. Now i am using sort of a queing system. This works, its just not as fast as i would like it to be.

Comment: You cannot share a connection between threads.  They're not multi-thread safe objects.